# Visual Studio 2015 Community crash on starting

Tags: visual-studio-2015, crash

I have booted my PC, started VS 2015 Community. Logo window shows up and almost instantly crashes without any messages but with error sound. Exact sound I have found in sound settings of Windows 7 described as "Default sound" or "Standard sound" (I have not english version).

In the last session (yesterday) it worked normally and here wasn't any changes in the system.

What could go wrong?

Here is the log:

```
  <entry>
    <record>26</record>
    <time>2017/03/09 10:29:56.022</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>LegacySitePackage failed for package [Async Query Service Package]Source: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.14.0&apos; Description: &#x041D;&#x0435; &#x0443;&#x0434;&#x0430;&#x043B;&#x043E;&#x0441;&#x044C; &#x0437;&#x0430;&#x0433;&#x0440;&#x0443;&#x0437;&#x0438;&#x0442;&#x044C; &#x0444;&#x0430;&#x0439;&#x043B; &#x0438;&#x043B;&#x0438; &#x0441;&#x0431;&#x043E;&#x0440;&#x043A;&#x0443; &quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&quot; &#x043B;&#x0438;&#x0431;&#x043E; &#x043E;&#x0434;&#x043D;&#x0443; &#x0438;&#x0437; &#x0438;&#x0445; &#x0437;&#x0430;&#x0432;&#x0438;&#x0441;&#x0438;&#x043C;&#x043E;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x0435;&#x0439;. &#x041E;&#x0436;&#x0438;&#x0434;&#x0430;&#x043B;&#x043E;&#x0441;&#x044C;, &#x0447;&#x0442;&#x043E; &#x043C;&#x043E;&#x0434;&#x0443;&#x043B;&#x044C; &#x0441;&#x043E;&#x0434;&#x0435;&#x0440;&#x0436;&#x0438;&#x0442; &#x043C;&#x0430;&#x043D;&#x0438;&#x0444;&#x0435;&#x0441;&#x0442; &#x0441;&#x0431;&#x043E;&#x0440;&#x043A;&#x0438;.&#x000D;&#x000A;System.BadImageFormatException: &#x041D;&#x0435; &#x0443;&#x0434;&#x0430;&#x043B;&#x043E;&#x0441;&#x044C; &#x0437;&#x0430;&#x0433;&#x0440;&#x0443;&#x0437;&#x0438;&#x0442;&#x044C; &#x0444;&#x0430;&#x0439;&#x043B; &#x0438;&#x043B;&#x0438; &#x0441;&#x0431;&#x043E;&#x0440;&#x043A;&#x0443; &quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&quot; &#x043B;&#x0438;&#x0431;&#x043E; &#x043E;&#x0434;&#x043D;&#x0443; &#x0438;&#x0437; &#x0438;&#x0445; &#x0437;&#x0430;&#x0432;&#x0438;&#x0441;&#x0438;&#x043C;&#x043E;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x0435;&#x0439;. &#x041E;&#x0436;&#x0438;&#x0434;&#x0430;&#x043B;&#x043E;&#x0441;&#x044C;, &#x0447;&#x0442;&#x043E; &#x043C;&#x043E;&#x0434;&#x0443;&#x043B;&#x044C; &#x0441;&#x043E;&#x0434;&#x0435;&#x0440;&#x0436;&#x0438;&#x0442; &#x043C;&#x0430;&#x043D;&#x0438;&#x0444;&#x0435;&#x0441;&#x0442; &#x0441;&#x0431;&#x043E;&#x0440;&#x043A;&#x0438;.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x0418;&#x043C;&#x044F; &#x0444;&#x0430;&#x0439;&#x043B;&#x0430;: &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Immutable.10.0, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a&apos;&#x000D;&#x000A;   &#x0432; Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.RegisterToolboxItemDiscoveryFactories()&#x000D;&#x000A;   &#x0432; Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   &#x0432; Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.AsyncQueryService.AsyncQueryServicePackage.Initialize()&#x000D;&#x000A;   &#x0432; Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Package.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.Interop.IVsPackage.SetSite(IServiceProvider sp)&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x041F;&#x0440;&#x0435;&#x0434;&#x0443;&#x043F;&#x0440;&#x0435;&#x0436;&#x0434;&#x0435;&#x043D;&#x0438;&#x0435;: &#x0440;&#x0435;&#x0433;&#x0438;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x0440;&#x0430;&#x0446;&#x0438;&#x044F; &#x043F;&#x0440;&#x0438;&#x0432;&#x044F;&#x0437;&#x043A;&#x0438; &#x0441;&#x0431;&#x043E;&#x0440;&#x043E;&#x043A; &#x0432;&#x044B;&#x043A;&#x043B;&#x044E;&#x0447;&#x0435;&#x043D;&#x0430;.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x0427;&#x0442;&#x043E;&#x0431;&#x044B; &#x0432;&#x043A;&#x043B;&#x044E;&#x0447;&#x0438;&#x0442;&#x044C; &#x0440;&#x0435;&#x0433;&#x0438;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x0440;&#x0430;&#x0446;&#x0438;&#x044E; &#x043E;&#x0448;&#x0438;&#x0431;&#x043E;&#x043A; &#x043F;&#x0440;&#x0438;&#x0432;&#x044F;&#x0437;&#x043A;&#x0438; &#x0441;&#x0431;&#x043E;&#x0440;&#x043E;&#x043A;, &#x0443;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x0430;&#x043D;&#x043E;&#x0432;&#x0438;&#x0442;&#x0435; &#x0437;&#x043D;&#x0430;&#x0447;&#x0435;&#x043D;&#x0438;&#x0435; &#x043F;&#x0430;&#x0440;&#x0430;&#x043C;&#x0435;&#x0442;&#x0440;&#x0430; &#x0440;&#x0435;&#x0435;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x0440;&#x0430; [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) &#x0432; 1.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x041F;&#x0440;&#x0438;&#x043C;&#x0435;&#x0447;&#x0430;&#x043D;&#x0438;&#x0435;. &#x0420;&#x0435;&#x0433;&#x0438;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x0440;&#x0430;&#x0446;&#x0438;&#x044F; &#x043E;&#x0448;&#x0438;&#x0431;&#x043E;&#x043A; &#x043F;&#x0440;&#x0438;&#x0432;&#x044F;&#x0437;&#x043A;&#x0438; &#x0441;&#x0431;&#x043E;&#x0440;&#x043E;&#x043A; &#x043C;&#x043E;&#x0436;&#x0435;&#x0442; &#x043F;&#x0440;&#x0438;&#x0432;&#x0435;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x0438; &#x043A; &#x043D;&#x0435;&#x043A;&#x043E;&#x0442;&#x043E;&#x0440;&#x043E;&#x043C;&#x0443; &#x0441;&#x043D;&#x0438;&#x0436;&#x0435;&#x043D;&#x0438;&#x044E; &#x043F;&#x0440;&#x043E;&#x0438;&#x0437;&#x0432;&#x043E;&#x0434;&#x0438;&#x0442;&#x0435;&#x043B;&#x044C;&#x043D;&#x043E;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x0438;.&#x000D;&#x000A;&#x0427;&#x0442;&#x043E;&#x0431;&#x044B; &#x043E;&#x0442;&#x043A;&#x043B;&#x044E;&#x0447;&#x0438;&#x0442;&#x044C; &#x044D;&#x0442;&#x0443; &#x0444;&#x0443;&#x043D;&#x043A;&#x0446;&#x0438;&#x044E;, &#x0443;&#x0434;&#x0430;&#x043B;&#x0438;&#x0442;&#x0435; &#x043F;&#x0430;&#x0440;&#x0430;&#x043C;&#x0435;&#x0442;&#x0440; &#x0440;&#x0435;&#x0435;&#x0441;&#x0442;&#x0440;&#x0430; [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].&#x000D;&#x000A;</description>
    <guid>{DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}</guid>
    <hr>80131018</hr>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>27</record>
    <time>2017/03/09 10:29:56.022</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>SetSite failed for package [Async Query Service Package](null)</description>
    <guid>{DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}</guid>
    <hr>80131018</hr>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>28</record>
    <time>2017/03/09 10:29:56.024</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>End package load [Async Query Service Package]</description>
    <guid>{DD7B74B5-C1F9-411A-B22E-5E711592BC6B}</guid>
    <hr>80131018</hr>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>29</record>
    <time>2017/03/09 10:29:56.031</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>AppId stopped registry detouring</description>
  </entry>
```

And so VS starts shutdown:

```
  <entry>
    <record>30</record>
    <time>2017/03/09 10:29:56.031</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Shutting down pkgdef registry</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>31</record>
    <time>2017/03/09 10:29:56.031</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>Released pkgdef cache usage tracker</description>
  </entry>
  <entry>
    <record>32</record>
    <time>2017/03/09 10:29:56.031</time>
    <type>Information</type>
    <source>VisualStudio</source>
    <description>PkgDef registry shutdown complete</description>
  </entry>
```

`ActivityLog.xsl` file doesn't look usefull but I can add it as well.

I didn't find any events in windows log for this time.

Comment: look in Eventlog for more details and managed callstack where the crash happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rapair from instalation menu solved the problem.